# Giving access to a PostgreSQL doesn't work

Tags: postgresql

i want to give read only access to a user in my Postgres database.
I have created the user and gave read access to certain schema's and add his IP in pg_hba.config file,but the issue is that the user don't have a particular IP ,today he connects from a different IP and get's the same error.So adding the IP to pg_hba is not an option.

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "67.xxx.xxx.53", user "abc_read", database "postgres", SSL on FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "67.xxx.xxx.53"
```

So is there a way to give access via SSH Key or certificates, not sure how certificates works in postgres?

can anyone give me a hint/suggestion on this?

Comment: Maybe try `cert` authentication or `ident` authentication? Does it need to be confined to a specific IP address? Can it be an IP range? You can set a CIDR mask on the IP to create a range, if that is acceptable for you

Comment: @richyen No, it will not be in an IP range,So giving range won't work. How can i use cert/ident authentication? So editing pg_hba config won't help right?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-cert.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/auth-ident.html